# Creating userdefined function returning XML using smo

Tags: c#, sql, xml, smo

I am attempting to create a UDF returning XML as so

```
Server s = new Server();
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database db = s.Databases["EDI"];
UserDefinedFunction udf = new UserDefinedFunction(db, "fxx");
udf.Schema = "dbo";
udf.TextMode = false;
udf.FunctionType = UserDefinedFunctionType.Scalar;
udf.ImplementationType = ImplementationType.TransactSql;

udf.DataType.SqlDataType = SqlDataType.Xml;
udf.DataType = DataType.Xml("Xml");        
udf.TextBody = "begin \r\n\t return '<root>test</root>' End;";
try {
    udf.Create();
} catch (Exception ex) {

    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

and it throws an exception

> Collection specified does not exist in metadata : 'Xml'

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

udf.DataType=DataType.Xml("") resolved the problem..